# Call a function if a checkbox is selected google sheets

Tags: if-statement, checkbox, google-sheets, nested, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to find a solution to the issue I have. 
I have checkboxes in column A. What I need is when one of them is checked, to populate a function/formula in a cell next to it (column B).

For example, I checked the checkbox in cell A10 and formula is being populated in cell B10.

The formula/function I have is a long IF function.

Hoping someone will be able to assist.

Comment: Can you provide an example or the copy of the sheet to try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Kessy Added the link in the comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(QUERY({""; IFERROR(REPT("♦ ", LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(INDIRECT("A12:A"&
 MAX(IF(A12:A=TRUE, ROW(A12:A), )))=FALSE, "♣", "♥"),,999^99), "♥")), " ", ))-COUNTA(
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!A1,  FILTER(Sheet5!C1:C,   Sheet5!C1:C  <>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!B1:B,   "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!J1,  FILTER(Sheet5!L1:L,   Sheet5!L1:L  <>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!K1:K,   "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!S1,  FILTER(Sheet5!U1:U,   Sheet5!U1:U  <>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!T1:T,   "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!AB1, FILTER(Sheet5!AD1:AD, Sheet5!AD1:AD<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!AC1:AC, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!AK1, FILTER(Sheet5!AM1:AM, Sheet5!AM1:AM<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!AL1:AL, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!AT1, FILTER(Sheet5!AV1:AV, Sheet5!AV1:AV<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!AU1:AU, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!BC1, FILTER(Sheet5!BE1:BE, Sheet5!BE1:BE<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!BD1:BD, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!BL1, FILTER(Sheet5!BN1:BN, Sheet5!BN1:BN<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!BM1:BM, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!BU1, FILTER(Sheet5!BW1:BW, Sheet5!BW1:BW<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!BV1:BV, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!CD1, FILTER(Sheet5!CF1:CF, Sheet5!CF1:CF<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!CE1:CE, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS"))))
 ))))))))))+1))}, IF(COUNTIF(A12:A, TRUE)<2, "offset 1", ), 0)&QUERY(IF(A12:A=TRUE,
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!A1,  "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!C1:C,   NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!B1:B,   "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!J1,  "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!L1:L,   NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!K1:K,   "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!S1,  "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!U1:U,   NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!T1:T,   "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!AB1, "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!AD1:AD, NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!AC1:AC, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!AK1, "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!AM1:AM, NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!AL1:AL, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!AT1, "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!AV1:AV, NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!AU1:AU, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!BC1, "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!BE1:BE, NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!BD1:BD, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!BL1, "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!BN1:BN, NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!BM1:BM, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!BU1, "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!BW1:BW, NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!BV1:BV, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))),
 IF($B$11=Sheet5!CD1, "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, FILTER(Sheet5!CF1:CF, NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet5!CE1:CE, "MATERIAL|DISPOSAL|PLANTS")))), 
 )))))))))), ), "where Col1 is not null", 0),,999^99), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation or some more details to your answer, simply  adding a line of code doesn't per say help understand OP or future community members the issue or the proposed solution.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! I did try to do it this way but it didn't work. What I forgot to mention is that the whole column A is only checkboxes and I would need this formula to work as an arrayformula. However, when I tried to convert it into array, it didn't work.

Comment: @Vladlen445 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @player0 Sorry for the late reply. Sure!
The "EXAMPLE" tab has a formula in cell B12 (same as you suggested).

What I need is to convert this formula into an array (or potentially change the whole thing) so that it is applied to the whole column. In other words, if I tick any of the checkboxes in column A, the formula will display the dropdown next to it. 

E.G. I tick the checkbox in cell A40 and I will get info next to cell B40 and going down. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tBbUiOi3wne70-mNCf4WyVf6YNPzLA7AsaePhkR3K2M/edit#gid=957040953

Comment: @player0 Thank you for helping so far. This is not exactly what I am looking for. I made a video explaining what exactly I am trying to achieve, please have a look if possible.

https://www.loom.com/share/82ab8324de0e4c47921d53da0d0cbb25

Comment: yes, the script would be a way to go but its possible to do it even without it (in a way)

Comment: @player0 The way you made it work is great! Thank you so much, I am very grateful for your help! One last question. I need column C to work the same way. The formula in column C is the same as in column B (just different ranges) and I was able to adjust the one you provided to work. However, there is one slight difference, unlike column B, it ignores "PLANTS","MATERIAL","DISPOSAL" and also blank cells. I am not sure how to change it to ignore blanks. Normally it would be <>"" but I can't add "" because the ignored words are already in "". Any suggestions?

Comment: if its FILTER withhin TEXTJOIN you dont need to specify empty cells coz 2nd parameter of textjoin set to 1 will remove all blanks. if FILTER is not within textjoin then you can add it outside of regex like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuP9z.png